# Redirect subfolder URL to Subdomain

Tags: .net, url, redirect, azure

I would like to redirect abc.com/yyy to xxx.abc.com, may i know how do i achieve this in domain manager?

Actually this is a .net MVC project hosted in Azure, may i know this is to be done at domain manager or ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you hosting in sites or cloud services?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to do in order to make this work:

1. Configure a **CNAME** for your abc.com domain, **xxx.abc.com** which points to **yourapplication.cloudapp.net** (you don't do this in the Azure portal, this is something you do on the website where you manager your domain settings).
2. Configure the **/yyy** subdirectory as an additional site in the Web Role as explained here: [How to Configure a Web Role for Multiple Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx). This will allow you to map a host header (**xxx.abc.com**) to the sub directory (**/yyy.com**). Once you have done this, you sub directory will also be available through **xxx.abc.com**
3. If you also want to set up a redirect redirect from **abc.com/yyy** to **xxx.abc.com** you will need to set up an URL Rewrite with the action type set to **Redirect** ([as explained here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)).

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done programmatically through global.asax.
Im using this to redirect from

> http://www.mysite.com

to

> http://mysite.com

Here is the code to do this.

```
public class SubdomainRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData returnValue = null;
        var url = httpContext.Request.Headers["HOST"];
        var index = url.IndexOf(".");
        if (index < 0)
            return returnValue;


        string subDomain = url.Substring(0, index);
        switch (subDomain.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "www":
                returnValue = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                returnValue.Values.Add("controller", "Redirect");
                returnValue.Values.Add("action", "RedirectToRoot");

                break;
                /*case "live":
                returnValue = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                returnValue.Values.Add("controller", "Database");
                returnValue.Values.Add("action", "Index");
                returnValue.Values.Add("liveMode", true); // set parameter to 'true';
                break;*/
            default: // not a supported domain, return null;
                break;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// required override
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestContext"></param>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }


}

 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute());
```

}

When it finds the subdomain your searching for, it will redirect to an action.  Make sure this action returns `Redirect` to whichever path you want.